# 'exit' is giving warning even after including <stdlib.h>

Tags: c, linux, header-files

I am getting following warning even after including `<stdlib.h>`

`warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’`

Is anybody know why it is giving?

```
void Check_file(char *filepath)
{
        if(access( filepath, F_OK ) == -1 ) {
                printf("\nUnable to access : %s\n",filepath);

                exit(1);
        }
        return;
}
```

Comment: You should `#include` all of `<stdlib.h>` for `exit` and `<unistd.h>` for `access` and `<stdio.h>` for `printf` ; with all 3 includes, I get no warnings with `gcc -Wall -c` on Debian/Sid; however,; I suggest using `perror` or `strerror` (so also include `<errno.h>` and `string.h`). You may want to code `exit (EXIT_FAILURE)` for readability!

Comment: You could pass `-H` to `gcc` to understand what files are included.

Comment: Whenever you get such error it means you have forgotten some `#include`s here `#include<stdlib.h>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program [compiles without complaint](http://ideone.com/Mym3lZ) when the proper include files are provided.

```
#include <stdio.h>              /* needed for printf */
#include <stdlib.h>             /* needed for exit */
#include <unistd.h>             /* needed for access and F_OK */
void Check_file(char *filepath)
{
        if(access( filepath, F_OK ) == -1 ) {
                printf("\nUnable to access : %s\n",filepath);

                exit(1);
        }
        return;
}
int main () { return 0; }
```